# Jquery display variable into html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, divide

I have defined the following variable:

```
var TuesdaysRatio = myTuesdaysNewLikesTotal / myTuesdaysImpressionsOrganicTotal;
```

The `console.log(TuesdaysRatio);` is has the output in Chrome: `0.032636762568610575` . The next line in my script is the following:

```
$('div.ratio-div').html('<p>Tuesdays Likes per Organic Impressions Ratio ' + TuesdaysRatio + '</p>');
```

I am using JQuery to display the variable in a paragraph into an empty div (with the class `ratio-div`) created above the script tag. On my page instead of `Tuesdays Likes per Organic Impressions Ratio 0.032636762568610575` I have `Tuesdays Likes per Organic Impressions Ratio NaN` and I can't figure it out where is the issue...

Comment: Where do `myTuesdaysNewLikesTotal` and `myTuesdaysImpressionsOrganicTotal` come from? Could you show us the code to get those values?

Comment: I am getting `myTuesdaysNewLikesTotal` from the same `<script>` tag and `myTuesdaysImpressionsOrganicTotal` globally from another `<script>` tag. If I use `console.log` I receive the values that it should... Btw this is how I get the numbers: `var myThursdaysNewLikesTotal = 0; for(var i=0, len=myThursdaysNewLikesData.length; i<len; i++){ myThursdaysNewLikesTotal += parseFloat(myThursdaysNewLikesData[i][1]); }`

Comment: can you share the values for `myTuesdaysNewLikesTotal` and `myTuesdaysImpressionsOrganicTotal`

Comment: Yeah, and I figure it out where is my problem, I have to use unique ids/classes for the divs because it just display my last values... (I use a foreach for my app). Thank you for pointing me this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number it.. Use [Number()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) .. `parseInt` and `parseFloat` may change your result so go for `Number()` function which converts the object argument to a number that represents the object's value.

```
var TuesdaysRatio = Number(myTuesdaysNewLikesTotal / myTuesdaysImpressionsOrganicTotal);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise, I will use this way :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var TuesdaysRatio = Number(0.032636762568610575);
    $('div.ratio-div').html('<p>Tuesdays Likes per Organic Impressions Ratio ' + TuesdaysRatio + '</p>');
});
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var TuesdaysRatio = parseFloat(parseInt(myTuesdaysNewLikesTotal) / parseInt(myTuesdaysImpressionsOrganicTotal));
     $('div.ratio-div').html('<p>Tuesdays Likes per Organic Impressions Ratio ' + TuesdaysRatio + '</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse your value first:

```
var TuesdaysRatio = parseInt((myTuesdaysNewLikesTotal / myTuesdaysImpressionsOrganicTotal), 10);
```